# How can i create a procedure for select statement in 'IN Clause' for phpmyadmin

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures, phpmyadmin, in-clause

I want to create a procedure for a select query in which the where clause will have a IN Clause. I had created one procedure like below butu its not working-

```
CREATE DEFINER = `root`@`localhost` PROCEDURE `agentin` ( IN `code` VARCHAR( 100 ) ) NOT DETERMINISTIC NO SQL SQL SECURITY DEFINER 
BEGIN 
SELECT * FROM AgentInformation WHERE AgentCode IN (code);
END
```

After putting the In clause values like --> IN ('CG001','CG002')

I am getting null values and the query made by phpmyadmin was

```
SET @p0 = '''CG001'',''CG002''';
```

CALL `agentin` (
@p0
);

Please help regarding it , Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here it is an example -

```
DELIMITER $$

CREATE PROCEDURE procedure1(IN id_param VARCHAR(255))
BEGIN
  SET @sql = CONCAT('SELECT * FROM table WHERE id IN (', id_param, ')');
  PREPARE stmt FROM @sql;
  EXECUTE stmt;
  DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt;
END$$

DELIMITER ;

SET @id = '1,2,3,4,5';
CALL procedure1(@id);
```

Comment: Accept the answer if it is OK.